# Can't open link (header command) with php when executing it through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Problem I ran into making stuff work in my startpage website. I'm using ajax to get input from the user without reloading the page, but this has caused a few problems with my code. The ajax sends the input to be processed with php. Some times, the php code will decide to reload the page, or to open a link. I did this in two different ways. In one case, I would use jquery from within the php code, like such:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
echo "link = '$link';";
echo "window.open(link, '_blank');";
echo "window.open('index.php','_self');";
echo "</script>";
```

In other cases, I would just refresh the page with the following command:

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

Neither work anymore. I wanted to have the option to reload the page when appropriate, but now I can never reload the page or even open links. Anybody has a fix?

This is what I have on the ajax side:

```
$('#searchBarGo').click(function() {
    var sb = $('#searchBar').val();
    $.post('index.php', {'sb': sb}, function(data) {
    });
    $("#searchBar").val('');
    return false;
});
```

And this is what I have on the php side:

```
if (isset($_POST['sb'])) {
    $originalcommand = $_POST['sb'];
    processcommand($originalcommand);
    return;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just saying using `header('Location: *')` is something that has to be 'abided' by the client. I could install a simple plugin that would deny those requests. Exit your php with `die()` or `exit()` after your header request because otherwise your PHP code will happily continue executing (even if I don't have that plugin installed).

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean, but what's the better way to do it then? I do have the problem of having to unblock popups from the startpage in new browsers.

Comment: I am not sure why both of your codes are not working, checked the developer console lately for JS errors? And what I mean with my previous comment, always use `die()` or `exit()` after a `header('Location: *')` function.

Comment: They used to work before. They stopped working after I started handling the php code with ajax, so that the page wouldn't load every time the user added an input.